# C#: making a two-dimensional array of panels

Tags: panels

I'm trying to write some code that displays a grid of panels (grid[]) onto a larger panel (gridHolder). Here's my code so far:

```
public void setupPanels(int x, int y)
    {

        grid = new Panel[y, x];
        this.Controls.Add(gridHolder);
        gridHolder.Show();
        gridHolder.Location = new Point(0 , 0);
        gridHolder.Size = new Size(x * PANEL_SIZE, y * PANEL_SIZE);

        for (int i = 0; i < grid.GetLength(0); i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < grid.GetLength(1); j++)
            {

                gridHolder.Controls.Add(grid[i, j]);
                grid[i, j].Location = new Point(i * PANEL_SIZE, j * PANEL_SIZE);
                gridHolder.Size = new Size(PANEL_SIZE, PANEL_SIZE);

            }

        }



    }
```

When I try to run the program, I get a debug error saying "NullReferenceException was unhandled". How can I fix my code?

Comment: It would be helpfull to know on what line you get the "NullReferenceException".

Answer (score 0):

Very far guess.. but try this:
In your `Page_Load` method alter the inner code so the line which calls `setupPanels` method will not call it on every entry but only in non-postback calls, should look something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        setupPanels(...)
}
```

Here is a full example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:panel ID="gridHolder" runat="server"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>



public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            SetupPanels(gridHolder, 40, 40, 6, 6);
    }

    private void SetupPanels(Panel panelsHolder, int widthPerPanel, int heightPerPanel, int panelsCountX, int panelsCountY)
    {
        panelsHolder.Style.Add("position","absolute");
        panelsHolder.Width = widthPerPanel*panelsCountX;
        panelsHolder.Height = heightPerPanel*panelsCountY;
        for (int y = 0; y < panelsCountY; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < panelsCountX; x++)
            {
                var gridPanel = new Panel
                {
                    Width = widthPerPanel,
                    Height = heightPerPanel,
                    BackColor = Color.SandyBrown,
                    BorderColor = Color.Black,
                    BorderWidth = 5,
                };
                gridPanel.Style.Add("position", "absolute");
                gridPanel.Style.Add("top", (x*widthPerPanel) + "px");
                gridPanel.Style.Add("left", (y*heightPerPanel) + "px");
                panelsHolder.Controls.Add(gridPanel);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be it. I'm looking around and it may have something to do with the panel class itself. Edit: apparently it can't be done because panel is a class and not a structure.

Comment: no such thing as can't be done - except taking a pee in the corner of a rounded room.